# Cannot resolve symbol 'v7'

Tags: android

I am new to android studio and i am facing error in my code. I tried multiple method but no solution.I tried changing changing versions also still no luck. I am facing 3 issue and my issue image is in this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wjqluGmWmbPLjpCoSzJ0MbM3_5hBIghm/view?usp=sharing
Below is my code. Thanks in Advance.

```
package com.example.cosmoar.ViewHolder;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.example.cosmoar.Interface.ItemClickListner;
import com.example.cosmoar.R;

public class ProductViewHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{

public TextView txtProductName, txtProductPrice;
public ImageView imageView;
public ItemClickListner listner;

public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull android.view.View itemView)
{
    super(itemView);

    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
    txtProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
    txtProductPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
}

public void setItemClickListner(ItemClickListner listner)
{
    this.listner = listner;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    listner.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), false);
}
}
```

and this what I have in my Build.gradle file

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}


android {
compileSdk 31


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.cosmoar"
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
implementation 'com.yarolegovich:sliding-root-nav:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Replace `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` with `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`.

Comment: i replaced that line but now i am getting different errors `'RecyclerView(android.content.Context)' in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView' cannot be applied to '(android.view.View)'` and `Cannot resolve method 'getAdapterPosition' in 'ProductViewHolder'`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and add this line `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. Your new code look as below.

```
public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
```

If your problem is the same, let me know by comment.

**EDIT -1 (UPDATE)**
change these 2 codes in your Original code.

1st

```
public class ProductViewHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
//to
public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
```

2nd

```
public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull android.view.View itemView)
{
//to
public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
{
```

If the problem is the same, let's change your first code with the below code.

```
public class ProductViewHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
//to
public class ProductViewHolder extends androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView implements View.OnClickListener
{
```

and your 2nd code is

```
public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull android.view.View itemView)
{
//to
public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
{
```

Comment: after changing my code it is working but app gets crash.

Comment: @Nayan ok, show me the Logcat error what error is showing.

Comment: or check this method `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` that @CommonsWare mentioned above.

Comment: ok, show me `Logcat` error when your app got crashed.

Comment: @M Dev there is no error in Logcat and when i try`androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView ` that @CommonsWare mentioned I get two error that **'RecyclerView(android.content.Context)' in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView' cannot be applied to '(android.view.View)'** and **Cannot resolve method 'getAdapterPosition' in 'ProductViewHolder'**

Comment: @Nayan let's change your code as I edited in my answer.

Comment: @M Dev when i change my code to `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` i am getting no error but my app is getting crash and there is no errors in `Logcat` as well but when i try `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` that @CommonsWare suggested i am getting two errors that i mentioned in above comment.

Comment: @Nayan updated your code as I updated in `EDIT -1` in my answer. let me know your feedback

Comment: @M Dev after updating code my getting error `Method does not override method from its superclass`

Comment: @Nayan, yes because this is super Class of Recycler.Adapter. Can I know what you want to do using this code?

Comment: @M Dev i am trying to get data that is in database. If its okay with you can we connect somewhere so i can show you my whole code?

Comment: @Nayan wait a minute, I'll give you the whole code to get data from the database.

Comment: @M Dev is my code wrong?

Comment: update your code as I updated in my EDIT 1 (UPDATED).